# Strange array behaviour regarding its length

Tags: arrays, bash

While writing a bash script I've encountered a strange problem: one array with a specific name has an unpredictable length, which somehow depends on its input. All the other arrays behave correctly. This is what I can observe:

- The problem persists, if I export the said array into other scripts
- If I rename the array, the problem goes away
- If I generate an array with the same name in some other script, it behaves correctly

Maybe it's some kind of memory allocation error, because there existed a variable with the exact same name which was NOT an array.

Here are some examples of the strangeness:

**original input**

```
ARRAY=(a b d f k l)
```

**bash output**

```
$ bash setup-env.sh
Array:
a
```

**original input**

```
ARRAY=(asdfasdf1 asdasdf2 asdfasdf3 asdfasdf4 asdfasdf5 asdfasdf6 asdfasdf7 asdfasdf8)
```

**bash output**

```
$ bash setup-env.sh
Array:
asdfasdf1
asdasdf2
asdfasdf3
asdfasdf4
asdfasdf5
asdfasdf6
asdfasdf7
asdfasdf8
```

**original input**

```
ARRAY=(ASD1 ASD2 ASD3 ASD4 ASD5 ASD6)
```

**bash output**

```
$ bash setup-env.sh
Array:
ASD1
ASD2
ASD3
ASD4
```

**original input**

```
ARRAY=(1asdf asdf)
```

**bash output**

```
$ bash setup-env.sh
Array:
1asdf
asdf
```

I'm curious as to why this happens

**EDIT:** `setup-env.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export FOLDER_NAME=(1asdf asdf)

echo "Array: "

for ((i = 0; i < ${#FOLDER_NAME}; i++)); do
    echo "${FOLDER_NAME[i]}"
done 


#. "write.sh"
```

The strange array in question is `FOLDER_NAME`. It's supposed to be exported for further use. Right now I can't use it, because it behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: `${#FOLDER_NAME}` is the count of characters of first element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your example output, your code is supposed to use the number of elements in the array, but is instead using the number of characters in the first element in the array.

The most likely cause is that you've written `${#ARRAY}` instead of `${#ARRAY[@]}`. If you fix that, it should work.

In the future, however, please be sure to include the relevant code in your questions here. Today I managed to be psychic (assuming I'm right), but that's obviously not something you can rely on!

(Incidentally, you don't even need `${#ARRAY[@]}` to print the elements of the array; you can just write `printf '%s\n' "${ARRAY[@]}"` or `for elem in "${ARRAY[@]}" ; do echo "$elem" ; done`.)

Comment: If you do want to iterate over the indexes of an array, `for i in "${!ARRAY[@]}"; do` (note the "!") works (and it works for associative arrays as well as numeric-indexed).

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. You're using 
`${#FOLDER_NAME}`

while the correct way is 
`${#FOLDER_NAME[@]}`

this is because if you have 
`ARRAY=(verylongstring basd ddf)` the output of `echo ${#ARRAY}` will be the lenght of the first variable.
The way to do it is:

`for i in ${ARRAY[@]}; do echo $i; done`

it works as expected.